# Travis CI for a Qt5 project

Tags: qt5, travis-ci

I am trying to use Travis CI with a Qt5 project, but I can't get the build to pass.

My `.travis.yml`

```
install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools

script:
  - qmake -project
  - qmake Ultron.pro
  - make
```

Last segment of the error log:

```
0.58s$ sudo apt-get install qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package qt5-default
E: Unable to locate package qttools5-dev-tools
The command "sudo apt-get install qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools" failed and exited with 100 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

Full log: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8296581/

Does this have something to do with it not being an official package?

Comment: Some self promotion here: [at the travis_cpp_tutorial GitHub](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/travis_cpp_tutorial) you can find dozens of Travis CI setups. [travis_qmake_gcc_cpp14_qt5](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/travis_qmake_gcc_cpp14_qt5) is the one that gives a minimal example answering your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add the correct repository and update apt:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update -qq
```

Your `.travis.yml` will then look like:

```
before_install:
 - sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
 - sudo apt-get update -qq
 - sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libsqlite3-dev
 - sudo apt-get install qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools

script:
 - qmake -project
 - qmake Ultron.pro
 - make
```

see: [Travis CI config to build against Qt5.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. Requires installing a PPA and certain packages for qt5 support. (jreese / gist:6207161)](https://gist.github.com/jreese/6207161)